# MySQL. Mix queries and display result only once

Tags: mysql

My web site publishes the events (music, theatre, exibitions...) that happen in my town (Italy). All the events have a start date and a end date. (Events that lasts only one day will have the same date).

All events may be displayed like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE end_date >= '".date("Y-m-d")."' ORDER BY end_date
```

The above statement will correctly list all the current events starting from today.

But there are some events that may happen at a certain point in the future and last more that one day (from-to event) for example:

> start_date = 2014-08-12 and end_date = 2014-08-23

An event with the above dates will be listed at the end because the MySQL query says:

> ORDER BY end_date

**It is possible to query MySQL so that it lists all the current events AND all those 'from-to' events which have in their date range a date equal to today ONLY ONCE?**

For example, let's say that **today = 2014-08-06** and there are a number of events that happen the same day:

```
Event 1: start_date=2014-08-06 / end_date=2014-08-06
Event 2: start_date=2014-08-07 / end_date=2014-08-07
Event 3: start_date=2014-08-08 / end_date=2014-08-08
Event 4: start_date=2014-08-09 / end_date=2014-08-09
```

and there's an other event with the following dates range:

```
Event 5: start_date=2014-08-01 / end_date=2014-08-20
```

which dates **include** the dates of events 1-4

The result expected should be:

**Event 5** - Event 1 - Event 2 - Event 3 - Event 4

**Event 5** is listed at the **first** place because it's date range includes the same date of **Event 1**, **BUT** must be listed only **ONCE** to avoid to be repeated every time all the other events (2-4) occur.

This must be avoided: **Event 5** - Event 1 - **Event 5** - Event 2 - **Event 5** - Event  3 - **Event 5** - Event 1 - **Event 5**.

Comment: This query won't return data in such order: Event 5 - Event 1 - Event 2 - Event 3 - Event 4 or even Event 5 - Event 1 - Event 5 - Event 2 - Event 5 - Event 3 - Event 5 - Event 1 - Event 5  Can You check and fix the question?

Comment: True, the query I wrote at the beginning does not do the job. I'm looking for help to build a new query that returns the result I expect: Event 5 - Event 1 - Event 2 - Event 3 - Event 4.

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM events WHERE end_date >= '".date("Y-m-d")."' ORDER BY end_date
>
> The above statement will correctly list all the current events starting from today.

No. This will return all events finishing from today. Some of them began in the past.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work.

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE "date("%Y-%m-%d")"  BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

Comment: No, this will list all BETWEEN events but not single-day events.

Comment: Query I have written is running on mysql console. For using it in php you need to get today date in a variable and the use it in the query.

Comment: You can use NOW(). as
SELECT * FROM events WHERE NOW()  BETWEEN start_date AND end_date